# Counting Query Results in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, count

I have run the following MYSQL query:

```
   SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,`original_date`, `last_modified_date`) 
   FROM `ft2_form_1` 
   WHERE `success` LIKE '1' 
   AND `color` LIKE '1'
```

This returns a series of numbers like this:
5
5
5
6
7
7
7
5
6

I would like to count the return values so the result would look something like this

```
    |  value  |   count  |
    ----------------------
    |       5 |        4 |
    |       6 |        2 |
    |       7 |        3 |
```

How would I modify my Query to return these results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT t.value,  COUNT(t.value) FROM
(
       SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,`original_date`, `last_modified_date`) AS value
       FROM `ft2_form_1` 
       WHERE `success` LIKE '1' 
       AND `color` LIKE '1'
) t
GROUP BY t.value
```

OR

```
   SELECT 
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,`original_date`, `last_modified_date`) AS value, COUNT(*)
   FROM `ft2_form_1` 
   WHERE `success` LIKE '1' 
   AND `color` LIKE '1'
   GROUP BY TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,`original_date`, `last_modified_date`)
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with the second option.  It did what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Query

```
SELECT table.value,  COUNT(table.value) FROM
(
    SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,`original_date`, `last_modified_date`) AS value
    FROM `ft2_form_1`        
        WHERE `success` LIKE '1' 
        AND `color` LIKE '1'
) table
GROUP BY table.value;
```